# will c++ 17 inline variables in headers be optimized out when they aren't referenced

Tags: c++, optimization, c++17, inline

In pre c++ 17 if I wanted to init something before the execution reaches `main()` I used static global in compilation units (.cpp files) and I use it from the classes that need this initialization so if those classes aren't used the static inits will be optimized out by the linker because it sees no reference to them .

Now after c++ 17 had come with inline variables I could move many small inits and global variables to the headers and everything works well , until I made a small thread pool to handle async io operations which is being referenced from the async io functions

so if the user of the library doesn't use any async io will the thread pool be optimized out or it will still run and launch its thread ?

Comment: It might be best to try it on a few compilers...

Comment: before trying it is better to see what the standard states about this because if it doesn't guarantee anything about this it will be compiler specific which may even change from release to another

Comment: As with many optimizations, it is probably the rule of the "as if" that apply. That is a compiler is free to do an optimization if it can prove that its effect cannot be observed in that program (excluding things like looking at the disassembly or measuring performance).

Comment: test with vs 2017 and it isn't get optimized out !

Comment: I have no proof, but I would be surprised if compiler could make that optimization. Unless it sees the whole code, only the linker could decide that it is not used.